# Heroku Push Failed

Tags: git, node.js, heroku

Here's the log:

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 79, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (76/76), done.
Writing objects: 100% (79/79), 228.60 KiB | 374.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 79 (delta 20), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Resolving engine versions
       Using Node.js version: 0.10.21
       Using npm version: 1.2.30
-----> Fetching Node.js binaries

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app

To git@heroku.com:some-heroku-app.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:some-heroku-app.git'
```

I've looked this error up, but no-one else's pushes seem to exit at quite the same place as mine. What's more is that it started quite randomly and I had already been pushing to this app today. I was doing everything the same and this is what happened. What's going on?

Comment: Think it has something to do with NPM?

Comment: I'm getting the same... just after getting the news from heroku to upgrade node.js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

same… temporarily fixed by explicitly requiring `"node": "0.10.20"`… I am assuming this will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

If fat's answer isn't working for you, try adding this to the dependencies object of your package.json file.

```
"node": "latest"
```